# Will an aluminum layer affect a magnet's attraction to steel?

Tags: electromagnetism

All else being equal.

Let's say I have a magnet with a 0.020" gap between the face of the magnet and a large piece of steel. Let's then say that I measure the attractive force between the magnet and the steel at 100 pounds.

Now, lets replace the 0.020" air gap between the steel and the magnet with a 0.020" thick aluminum layer. In both cases the gap between the magnet and the steel is exactly the same. Will that change the attractive force of the magnet?

Air gap:

[image: Air gap between steel and magnet]

Aluminum gap:

[image: Aluminum between steel and magnet]

Answer (score 0):

Since magnets only interact with ferromagnetic materials the aluminum won't have an impact on the attractive force of the magnet to the steel. There is a better explanation of this on K&J Magnetics, [Magnet Basics](https://www.kjmagnetics.com/blog.asp?p=magnet-basics) and [Shielding Materials](https://www.kjmagnetics.com/blog.asp?p=shielding-materials).

Comment: Strictly speaking this isn't correct; aluminum is paramagnetic and so will develop its own magnetic field in response to the fields of the magnet and the steel.  It will be a small effect, of course, but it won't be zero.